# Panel shows 0 controls after they are dynamically added

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, development

I have added several labels and a checkbox to a panel on a user control (in a visual web part) at page load (specifically in an override of OnPreRender). Now when I try to iterate through them, it is as if they don't exist (though they are displayed on the page). When I debug the solution, thepanel.contols.count shows 0. I will attempt to extract the relevant bits of code:

controls are added like this:

```
pnlDeptEvents.Controls.Add(lblTitle);
pnlDeptEvents.Controls.Add(lblLocation);
pnlDeptEvents.Controls.Add(chkAttending);
pnlDeptEvents.Controls.Add(lblTime);
pnlDeptEvents.Controls.Add(lblEvent);
```

All controls are definitely added to the page, because I can see them there.

When the submit button is clicked, I am trying to work through the listed events to see which are being requested (checked).

```
int cCount = pnlDeptEvents.Controls.Count;
foreach (Control c in pnlDeptEvents.Controls)
{
    if(c is CheckBox)
{
    CheckBox box = (CheckBox)FindControl(c.ID);
    if(box.Checked)
    {
                string session = box.ID;
                sessions.Add(session);
            }
    }
}
```

pnlDeptEvents.Controls.Count always shows as 0. Do I have to do something in between these steps?

TIA